# How to return the parent Abstract class instead of the Child classes in Java

Tags: java, abstract-class

Imagine that I have a Parent abstract class

```
public abstract class ParentAbstract {}
```

And one Child

```
public abstract class ChildA extends ParentAbstract {}
```

If I have a method that returns a list of ChildA that looks like this:

```
private List<ChildA> results() {
  return new ArrayList<ChildA>();
}
```

Why can't I use this method like so? Which calls the above results method

```
private List<Parent<?>> absctractResults() {
  return results();
}
```

The compiler will throw

```
java: incompatible types: List<ChildA> cannot be converted to List<Parent<?>>
```

Why can't the compiler allow that and how to make a method that returns a list of the abstract class that calls other methods returning the child classes?

Comment: Why did you putted `<?>` at `IncomingMessageAbstract`? You parent has no generic.

Comment: As soon as you give a `List<ChildA>` one cannot turn it into a `List<ParentAbstract>` as putting an ParentAbstract in the list, would corrupt others holding a `List<ChildA>` - they think. Hence not allowed.

Comment: You can do this kind of cast `return (List<ParentAbstract>)(List<?>)results();`, but I'm not sure that is a good idea.

Comment: @KunLun You're right, I can totally remove that

Comment: I found a way to convert the list from the results() method :
`new ArrayList<>(results.getResults())` is allowed to return a `List<Parent>` 

Thanks for your help!